# How to reassign a variable with a function?

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list called board like this:

```
board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I've written a function that outputs this board to the console looking like a sudoku board:

```
def print_board(bo):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("- - - + - - - + - - -")

        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                print("| ", end="")

            if j == 8:
                print(bo[i][j])
            else:
                print(str(bo[i][j]) + " ", end="")

print_board(board)

>>>
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
- - - + - - - + - - -
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
- - - + - - - + - - -
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
```

Now I don't want to output this board to the console but rather reassign the variable board to a string that's the "converted" board. How would I do that?

Comment: So have you tried building a string instead of using print? What happened?

Comment: Yes i have and when I do that it outputs "None".

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think on how the print behaves, then assign an empty string, and keep concatenating whatever you print to that string.

So for a  normal `print`, append a newline at the end of the string and for a `print with end=""` parameter,  we won't append anything, also convert integer to string as well

```
def print_board(bo):

    s = ''
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            s += "- - - + - - - + - - -\n"

        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                s += "| "

            if j == 8:
                s += str(bo[i][j])+'\n'
            else:
                s += str(bo[i][j]) + " "

    return s
```

Then your output will be

```
board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

print(print_board(board))
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
- - - + - - - + - - -
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
- - - + - - - + - - -
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
```